# Chapter header runs off the side of the page on a few random horizontal pages

Tags: header-footer, horizontal

Edited

I am very new to LaTeX and I have just compiled my thesis using twoside (it had been oneside previously). On a few random horizontal pages the Chapter header (which has been shortened using \chaptermark{}) is offset and runs off the side.

[image]

Here is some compilable code and the image I use is attached:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book} %,PageStyleII,times,numbering,print,custombib
\usepackage{geometry}                       % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{a4paper}                          % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\captionsetup[figure]{font={small}, skip=1pt, singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font={small}, skip=1pt, singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[table]{font={small}, skip=1pt, singlelinecheck=false}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{enumitem}

%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{natbib}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

% ******************************** Main Matter *********************************
\mainmatter

\chapter{Assessing the evidence for microenvironments in craters}
\label{chap:micro}
\chaptermark{Microenvironments in craters}

%********************************** %5th Section  **************************************
\section{The environment at Kaiser crater} 

Blah blah blah

\subsection{Surface temperature}

The blah blah blah

\newpage

blah blah

\newpage

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.95\hsize]{Micro/windsx4_Kaiser_ls110.png}
\caption{one page horizontal which plots ok.}
\label{fig:ktsurf}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{subfigure}{0.95\hsize}
    \subcaption{\bf SH mid-summer}
    \label{fig:ktsurf_110}
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\hsize]{Micro/windsx4_Kaiser_ls110.png}
\end{subfigure}             
\caption{This plots chapter header offset.}
\label{fig:ktsurf_winds}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]\ContinuedFloat
\begin{center}
\begin{subfigure}{0.95\hsize}
    \subcaption{\bf SH late autumn}
    \label{fig:ktsurf_230}
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\hsize]{Micro/windsx4_Kaiser_ls110.png}
\end{subfigure}             
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption[]{This plots OK}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]\ContinuedFloat
\begin{center}
\begin{subfigure}{0.95\hsize}
    \subcaption{\bf SH early spring}
    \label{fig:ktsurf_350}
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\hsize]{Micro/windsx4_Kaiser_ls110.png}
\end{subfigure}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption[]{This plots OK}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

This only happens when the second horizontal page is on the right hand side / is an even page number. When I compiled it and the first horizontal page was on the right hand side, the rest was all fine.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: As you said, it only appears in "apparently random places". So it would be vastly helpful if you can provide a compilable document that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, Willie. I have updated the code and included the image.

Comment: Do not make a single landscape environment, but one for each figure.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks very much, Fran.